# perl match part of string in two files

Tags: perl

I'm using a perl script to look for matches between columns in two tab-delimited files. However for one column I only want to look for a partial match between two strings in two columns.

It concerns $row[4] of $table2 and $row{d} of $table1.
The values in $row[4] of $table2 look like this:
'xxxx'.
The values in $row{d} of $table1 look like this:
'xxxx.aaa'.

If the part before the '.' is the same, there is a match. If not, there is no match. I'm not sure how to implement this in my script. This is what I have so far. I only looks for complete matches between different columns. '...' denotes code that is not important for this question

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

...

...

chomp( my @header_table2 = split /\t/, <$table2> );

my %lookup;
while(<$table2>){
    chomp;
    my @row = split(/\t/);
    $lookup{ $row[0] }{ $row[1] }{ $row[4] }{ $row[5] }{ $row[6] }{ $row[7] }{ $row[8] } = [ $row[9], $row[10] ];
    } 

my @header = do {
    my $header = <$table1>;
    $header =~ s/\t?\n\z//;
    split /\t/, $header;
   };

print $table3 join ("\t", @header, qw/ name1 name2 /), "\n";


{
no warnings 'uninitialized';
while(<$table1>){
    s/\t?\n\z//;
    my %row;
    @row{@header} = split /\t/;
    print $table3 join ( "\t", @row{@header},
                   @{ $lookup{ $row{a} }{ $row{b} }{ $row{c} }{ $row{d} }{ $row{e} }{ $row{f} }{ $row{g} }
                        // [ "", "" ] }), "\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a scoping problem because your array `@row` and your hash `%row` both exist in completely different scopes.

But if you have variables (say, `$foo` and `$bar`) and you want to know if `$foo` starts with the contents of `$bar` followed by a dot, then you can do that using a regular expression check like this:

```
if ($foo =~ /^$bar\./) {
  # match
} else {
  # no match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is looking like a job for a database

The solution below isn't going to work, because you are building your `%lookup` hash with nine levels of keys (`$row[0]` .. `$row[8]`) , and accessing it with only seven levels (`$row{a}` .. `$row{g}`), so you're going to have to edit in the real situation

I see no reason to next your hashes so deeply. A single key formed by using `join` on the relevant fields will work fine and probably a little faster. I also see no reason to extract `table2` fields into an array and `table1` fields into a hash. An array seems fine in both cases

I've solved your immediate problem by copying each `@row` from `table1` into array `@key`, and removing the last dot and anything following from the fourth element before building the `$key` string

In view of your history of adding a spare tab character before the newline at the end of each record, I've also added four `die` statements that verify the size of the header row and columns rows before continuing. You will probably need to tweak those values according to your real data

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

use constant TABLE1_COLUMNS => 9;
use constant TABLE2_COLUMNS => 11;

open my $table2, '<', 'table2.txt' or die $!;

my @header_table2 = do {
    my $header = <$table2>;
    $header =~ s/\t?\n\z//;
    split /\t/, $header;
};
die "Incorrect table 2 header count " . scalar @header_table2
    unless @header_table2 == TABLE2_COLUMNS;

my %lookup;

while ( <$table2> ) {
    chomp;
    my @row = split /\t/;
    die "Incorrect table 2 column count " . scalar @row
        unless @row == TABLE2_COLUMNS;

    my $key = do {
        local $" = "\n";
        "@row[0..8]";
    };

    $lookup{ $key } = [ @row[9,10] ];
} 

open my $table1, '<', 'table1.txt' or die $!;

my @header = do {
    my $header = <$table1>;
    $header =~ s/\t?\n\z//;
    split /\t/, $header;
};
die "Incorrect table 1 header count " . scalar @header
    unless @header == TABLE1_COLUMNS;


open my $table3, '>', 'table3.txt' or die $!;


print $table3 join ("\t", @header, qw/ name1 name2 /), "\n";


while ( <$table1> ) {

    s/\t?\n\z//;

    my @row = split /\t/;
    die "Incorrect table 1 column count " . scalar @row
        unless @row == TABLE1_COLUMNS;

    my $key = do {
        my @key = @row;
        $key[3] =~ s/\.[^.]*\z//;
        local $" = "\n";
        "@key";
    };

    my $lookup = $lookup{ $key } // [ "", "" ];

    print $table3 join("\t", @row, @$lookup), "\n";
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but my $table 1 contains around 50 columns, so @{ $lookup{ $row{a} }{ $row{b} }{ $row{c} }{ $row{d} }{ $row{e} }{ $row{f} }{ $row{g} } refers actually to the names of the columns (on the first row). So I don't think that your solution will work in this case.

Comment: @user1987607: I don't see any reason for your doubt. Have you tried my code? I can't really help further unless you show your real data.

Comment: the reason why I doubt is that table1 contains 9 columns, but table 2 contains 50 columns (not just 'a' to 'g'), so I'm matching the 9 columns of table1 with columns of table 2 that are named 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ..., but are not just the first 9 columns of this table2.

Comment: @user1987607: It is not my solution that is at fault but your expression of the problem. Did you read that I said ***"The solution below isn't going to work, because ..."***? You haven't given enough information and your own code isn't self-consistent. Using a hugely-nested data structure instead of a simple compound key isn't going to suddenly make you code work. If you can't use what I have written here then I think you must open a new question and deliver a fully-working example together with sample data that displays the same issue.